# Refresh excel inside a loop in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, refresh

I am having an issue while I am trying to refresh my excel sheet inside a loop in vba.
I run a loop, extract data from SAP in a .txt file and try to update it in excel via the refresh button for each step of my loop, the problem is, the refresh doesn't occur until the end of the loop. I've tried many things I red on internet like adding the command "DoEvents" after my command "ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll". I've also tried:

```
dTime = Time
Do While Time < dTime + 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 / 2
 DoEvents
Loop
```

which didn't work
I've tried:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Didn't work too.

If you had the same issue and found a solution, even one that costs time, I'll take it.
Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you're doing in the rest of your code - that would likely be relevant here...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see what you are doing with the data from the text file.  But as a general rule, to see the screen refresh while a long-running process is going, give this a try:

```
Sub read_data_from_files()
    
    Dim x As Integer
    For x = 1 To 100
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      ' read a text file and write the results to the worksheet
      DoEvents
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Next

End Sub
```

Microsoft has changed how it updates the screen while a VBA program is running over the years to improve performance.  So this solution will depend on which version of Excel you are using.  If this does not work for you, please provide mode detail about what you are doing and share the version of Excel and the operating system you are using.